# add a (x,y) point to area chart in Excel

Tags: excel, charts

using the following coordinates I have the following graph

```
0.22    581.5
0.32    800
0.46    800
```

I would like to add a point at (0.32,400) how is the possible procedure in excel?

I have tried to combine graphs together but unsuccessfully

[image]

Comment: You should use a scatter chart if you want to plot points.

Comment: yes but how to combine area chart and scatter plot, thats where I have issues

Comment: See [here](https://blogs.office.com/2012/06/21/combining-chart-types-adding-a-second-axis/) for combining chart types in excel.

Comment: @Irfan434 I have been trying but with area and scatter chart is not that straightforward, could you please provide me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Right click on your chart and select "select data"
- Add 1st and 3rd column in series
- Right click on chart and select "change series chart type"
- Select chart "Line with markers"
- You can hide line by clicking on line and select format data series

[image: Excel Chart]